# How to calculating percentage on sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I created a table in sqlite. There are ID, Name, Group, Salary columns. And I was told to add a Bonus column, which I have created. In the bonus column, I have to fill the value of the bonus received by 5% of my salary. I'm stuck here, do you know what query I should use?

Comment: `update atable set bonus = salary * .05;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas is good for reading charts

```
import pandas as pd

def percent(expression):
    if "%" in expression:
        expression = expression.replace("%","/100")
    return eval(expression)

data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
Value = DataFrame.get_value('the index you want to take from', 'the column name', 'the role name', takeable = true)
Answer = percent("Value*5%")
```